# How to loop through folder names and move folders based on date in folder name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I currently have a batch file that loops through a text file which has a list of file names and moves these files to folders based on the date in the file name.

I'm trying now to change this to do something similar but for folders. Get folder names and then move each folder to another location based on the date in the folder name.

Example of folder structure:

Before move:

```
k:\PLPR1
k:\PLPR1\20210910\data
k:\PLPR1\20210909\data
k:\PLPR1\20210830\data
```

After move:

```
l:\PLPR1\2021\FTP Data\September\10 September\data
l:\PLPR1\2021\FTP Data\September\09 September\data
l:\PLPR1\2021\FTP Data\September\30 August\data
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder moving task can be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourcePath=K:\PLPR1"
set "TargetPath=L:\PLPR1"

set "Month01=January"
set "Month02=February"
set "Month03=March"
set "Month04=April"
set "Month05=May"
set "Month06=June"
set "Month07=July"
set "Month08=August"
set "Month09=September"
set "Month10=October"
set "Month11=November"
set "Month12=December"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourcePath%" /AD-L /B 2^>nul') do (
    set "FolderName=%%I"
    set "Year=!FolderName:~0,4!"
    set "Month=!FolderName:~4,2!"
    set "Day=!FolderName:~6,2!"
    for %%I in (Month!Month!) do set "Month=!%%I!"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SourcePath%\%%I" "%TargetPath%\!Year!\FTP Data\!Month!\!Day! !Month!" /E /MOVE /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS /R:1 /W:5 >nul
)
endlocal
```

The first two command lines define the required execution environment which is:

- command echo mode turned off
- command extensions enabled
- delayed environment variable expansion enabled

The enabled delayed expansion means that this batch file cannot be used without modification on source or target path containing one or more exclamation marks.

It is further expected by this batch file code that the source folder contains only subfolders with names being the date in format `yyyyMMdd`.

The usage of `for /F` with a command line enclosed in `'` results in running in background one more `cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the specified command line appended as additional arguments. So executed is in background with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "K:\PLPR1" /AD-L /B 2>nul
```

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The command **DIR** searches

- in specified directory for file system entries which
- have the directory attribute set and are not reparse points (directory junctions) because of option `/AD-L` and
- outputs in bare format just the names of the folders because of option `/B` without path.

The error message output by **DIR** on not finding any directory is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

The output of **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** of background command process is captured by **FOR** respectively `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself after finishing execution of **DIR**.

**FOR** with option `/F` results in always ignoring empty lines which do not occur here at all. A non-empty line would be split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. That line splitting behavior would be no problem here as the folder names in format `yyyyMMdd` do not contain a space character, but there is nevertheless used `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters which makes the processing of the file names a very little bit faster as line splitting behavior is turned off in this case.

If the first substring being now the entire directory name would start with a semicolon, **FOR** would also ignore the captured line for further processing. This end of line behavior does not matter here as the directory names do not start with a semicolon.

So there is in memory of the command process processing the batch file now a list of directory names which are assigned one after the other to the specified loop variable `I` and it does not matter anymore what happens next in the source directory during the loop iterations. This is important, especially if the source directory is on a FAT drive (FAT32, exFAT).

The directory name without path is assigned to an environment variable and substitutions are used next with delayed expansion to split the date in name up to year, month and day in month.

There are defined twelve environment variables which hold for each month with two digit month value at end of the variable name the appropriate name of the month. A simple **FOR** loop is used to concatenate the fixed string `Month` with the month value determined from directory name do redefine the environment variable `Month` using delayed expansion by the month name assigned to the dynamically built environment variable name starting with `Month` and ending with current month value.

Now all required data are available to move everything inside the current directory with **ROBOCOPY** to the appropriate destination directory using the year, month and day values. **ROBOCOPY** creates automatically the entire destination (target) directory tree.

It is of course possible that **ROBOCOPY** fails to delete a file/directory in source directory, for example if a file is currently opened in source directory by another application or a directory is the current directory of a running process. But that does not matter for the **FOR** loop as the command **FOR** itself does not access anymore the file system to get next directory name because of processing a list of directory names in memory of the command process. So it is not possible that any directory is processed more than once, or that a directory is skipped by chance, or the **FOR** loop runs into an endless loop thanks to first getting the list of directories to process loaded into memory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`